# Match regex with Java showing no match for + sign?

Tags: java, regex

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\+|-").matcher("a+b")
```

When I do `m.start()`

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
```

Why is this not working? This should have matched the `+` in `a+b`.

Comment: [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--)

Comment: You shouldn't use Matcher#start() before you've done a find() or match() operation.